# Aligning div elements (css, html)

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm a beginner when it comes to HTML and CSS and I'm struggling to position some div elements as described in the image [intended outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5geSW.png). I've centered the table with `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`. I want the *text* div-element to be aligned right above the table. Is there any good way to do that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them both in another div that will be centered inside the box

Set the table width and the div width.

```
<div id="wrapper-div" style="margin:auto; width:XXpx">
    <div id="text-div" style=""></div>
    <div id="table-div"></div>
</div>
```

The wrapper div should have the same width as the table div.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, as you are trying you can try adding the following css style:

```
 display:inline-block
```